# Lenovo Thinkbook 15iml battery drain issue with dual boot

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, power-management, lenovo, battery

I recently bought Lenovo Thinkbook 15iml and it works fine with Windows 10.
But as soon as I dual boot Windows and Linux (tried Ubuntu 20.04,Ubuntu 20.04.1 and Manjaro 20.1)the battery drainage issue kicks in and the battery starts draining even when the laptop is turned off.
I have already turn off Fastboot option in Windows and secure boot from BIOS and have updated all of the chip set drivers but still the issue is there.

The dmesg in Linux shows ACPI error

*acpi bios error (bug): could not resolve symbol [_sb.pci0.lpcb.hec.ecrd], ae_not_found (20190816/psargs-330)*

When I turn of ACPI in grub file they keypad, mouse pad or screen brightness stops working.

What should be the exact issue with this Thinkbook and what should I do to prevent battery drainage on duaboot?

Comment: *"the battery starts draining even when the laptop is turned off"* - What makes you believe that the problem has to do with Ubuntu?  This suggests a hardware issue because, well, Ubuntu isn't doing anything to your device when it's off.

Comment: I already mentioned that it is related to ACPI drivers which are not working well in dual boot conditions.

Comment: Drivers aren't doing anything when the laptop is off either. How did you determine this to be fact and not conjecture?

Comment: I'm suspecting that something is running even when the Laptop is shutdown. It's warm and which implies that the processor is somewhat running and has not been completely shutdown. Usually most of the laptop vendors do the ACPI implementation based on Microsoft's way so these laptops just work fine with Windows but whenever any other OS is used, the Power issues start to kick in.